# How to find a font with Globe symbols

Tags: fonts, unicode

Which font is used in http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F300.pdf?
I'm particular interested in the `GLOBE WITH MERIDIANS` glyph.

**Q:** Is there any free font that cover these Unicode block?

[image]

.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. However if you're asking which font is in use on that site the answer is 'Fedra Sans Alt Book 2"'

Comment: @PHPst Do you maybe mean the `GLOBE WITH MERIDIANS` symbol?

Comment: @nixda Yes, I do.

Answer (score 5):

I searched a while but wasn't able to find a suitable font. Nevertheless I want to share my research. Maybe it will help you to identify it on your own.

#### Use a bookmarklet to see which font is used on a website

1. Drag the [whatfont bookmarklet](http://chengyinliu.com/whatfont.html) to your browsers toolbar (works in every browser)
2. Go to your website and call the bookmarklet
3. Hover over any text (and click if you need additional infos)

> javascript:(function(){var d=document,s=d.createElement('scr'+'ipt'),b=d.body,l=d.location;s.setAttribute('src','http://chengyinliu.com/wf.js?o='+encodeURIComponent(l.href)+'&t='+(new Date().getTime()));b.appendChild(s)})();

#### Use a screenshot

Where fonts are embedded in images (like in your example) this bookmarklet won't help.
But [myfonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) or [whatfontis.com](http://www.whatfontis.com/) lets you upload screenshots and identifies the font if possible.

#### Search on font sites

Scroll down on [alanwood.net](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/search.html). The site offers a wide range of mathematical symbols.

#### Use the Unicode identifier

If you know the Unicode identifier, you could use [scarfboy.com](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/) and search for i.e. "1F30D".

```
U+1F30D         U+1F30E           U+1F30F         U+1F310
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Under section *Some fonts with this character* you'll see at least one containing font.

A second site which has a similar feature is [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm). if you search for 1F30D and click on *Fonts that support U+1F30D* you get a list of fonts which support your character. Of course each font could have a different interpretation of a character.

[image]